# Clojure: How to import Java interface with period separators in Class.Name

Tags: clojure, protocol-buffers

I am trying to import this class into Clojure:
`com.google.protobuf Message.Builder`

Neither of the following work:

```
import [com.google.protobuf Message.Builder]
import [com.google.protobuf Message$Builder] ;; imports the Class not the interface
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `Message$Builder` is correct.  See these examples:

```
com.google.protobuf.Message => <#java.lang.Class com.google.protobuf.Message>
(supers com.google.protobuf.Message) => #{com.google.protobuf.MessageLite com.google.protobuf.MessageLiteOrBuilder com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder}
(bases com.google.protobuf.Message) => (com.google.protobuf.MessageLite com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder)
(ancestors com.google.protobuf.Message) => #{com.google.protobuf.MessageLite com.google.protobuf.MessageLiteOrBuilder com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder}

com.google.protobuf.Message$Builder => <#java.lang.Class com.google.protobuf.Message$Builder>
(supers com.google.protobuf.Message$Builder) => #{com.google.protobuf.MessageLiteOrBuilder com.google.protobuf.MessageLite$Builder java.lang.Cloneable com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder}
(bases com.google.protobuf.Message$Builder) => (com.google.protobuf.MessageLite$Builder com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder)
(ancestors com.google.protobuf.Message$Builder) => #{com.google.protobuf.MessageLiteOrBuilder com.google.protobuf.MessageLite$Builder java.lang.Cloneable com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder}

com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder => <#java.lang.Class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder>
(supers com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder) => #{com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder com.google.protobuf.Message$Builder java.lang.Object com.google.protobuf.MessageLiteOrBuilder com.google.protobuf.MessageLite$Builder java.lang.Cloneable com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder}
(bases com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder) => (com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder com.google.protobuf.Message$Builder)
(ancestors com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage$Builder) => #{com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder com.google.protobuf.Message$Builder java.lang.Object com.google.protobuf.MessageLiteOrBuilder com.google.protobuf.MessageLite$Builder java.lang.Cloneable com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder}
```

If you go to [this javadoc page](https://sccn.ucsd.edu/~yute/API/PervasiveBCI_ForServer/doc/com/google/protobuf/AbstractMessage.Builder.html) you will see:

```
com.google.protobuf
Class AbstractMessage.Builder<BuilderType extends AbstractMessage.Builder>

java.lang.Object
com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite.Builder<BuilderType>
com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage.Builder<BuilderType>

All Implemented Interfaces:
Message.Builder, MessageLite.Builder, MessageLiteOrBuilder, MessageOrBuilder, java.lang.Cloneable

Direct Known Subclasses:
DynamicMessage.Builder, GeneratedMessage.Builder

Enclosing class:
AbstractMessage
```

So perhaps Clojure is just "reporting" it as a "class".

---

Yes, that seems to be the case.  Look at the interface `java.lang.Runnable`:

```
(class java.lang.Runnable)  => java.lang.Class 
java.lang.Runnable          => <#java.lang.Class java.lang.Runnable>
```

---

## Update

If you want to test a subclass, you need `isa?`:

```
(isa? clojure.lang.PersistentVector clojure.lang.IFn)  => true
(isa? java.lang.Integer java.lang.Number)              => true
```

`extends?` and `satisfies?` are only for Clojure protocols, which are different than Java class/interface hierarchies.

Comment: That makes sense. When I try check if a class satisfies this interface, though, I receive a NullPointerException.

    user> (satisfies? Message$Builder a)
    NullPointerException   clojure.core/instance?--5126 (core.clj:144)

Comment: Any ideas on why this would cause a NullPointerException?

Comment: Again, the `satisfies?` is only for protocols, you should perhaps use `isa?` in this case. This behavior probably follows Garbage-In-Garbage-Out philosophy. It fails with NPE because it tries to call `instance?` on the result of `(:on-interface protocol)`. See core-deftype/find-protocol-impl.